# C-c C-c is not working

Tags: key-bindings

I'm writing a major mode.
In that mode I put:

```
(define-key oef-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'oef-edit-in-browser) ;
```

With Aquamacs (on my mac) the shortcut is working as expected.
But with emacs (on linux) I get: `C-c C-c-` and the minibuffer is waiting for a key.

If I try <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>  I get same thing : `C-c C-c-`

After bisecting my init file, as Drew suggested, I found that the problem was the line :

```
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode) ;; Auto-start on any markup modes
```

If I disable emmet-mode `C-c C-c` is working fine with my mode... but I don't want to disable Emmet-mode because I like it very much.

**Solved**

I put that in my init file :

```
;;; EMMET-MODE
(defvar emmet-mode-keymap
  (let
      ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-j") 'emmet-expand-line)
    (define-key map (kbd "<C-return>") 'emmet-expand-line)
    (define-key map (kbd "<C-M-right>") 'emmet-next-edit-point)
    (define-key map (kbd "<C-M-left>") 'emmet-prev-edit-point)
    (define-key map (kbd "C-c w") 'emmet-wrap-with-markup)
    map)
  "Keymap for emmet minor mode.")

(require 'emmet-mode)
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode) ;; Auto-start on any markup modes
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'emmet-mode)
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook  'emmet-mode)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'emmet-mode)
```

**UPDATE**

The solution that gave Tyler is working fine. So I put that in my init file:

```
(require 'emmet-mode)
(eval-after-load "emmet-mode"
  '(define-key emmet-mode-keymap (kbd "C-c C-c") 'oef-edit-in-browser))
(eval-after-load "emmet-mode"
  '(define-key emmet-mode-keymap (kbd "C-c w") 'emmet-wrap-with-markup))
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode) ;; Auto-start on any markup modes
;; `emmet-mode' will automatically start with oef-mode
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'emmet-mode)
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook  'emmet-mode)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'emmet-mode)
```

Comment: Start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). Do you see the same problem? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: For the future, if you are in a similar situation (i.e. you are trying to describe a key, but you see that Emacs expects more keys (i.e. it shows `-` after the keys you already typed), you can type `?` (viz, in your case that would be `C-c C-c ?`) and that will show you possible other keys defined for this prefix. Once you know what function is bound to the key, it is usually trivial to locate the library which defined it, and make sure it doesn't do it / defines it differently.

Comment: If @Tyler's answer works for you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the minibuffer shows `C-c C-c-`, that indicates Emacs is still waiting for a complete key sequence. The same thing happens when you enter `C-x` - you'll see `C-x-` in the minibuffer, as Emacs waits for the rest of the command.

The reason Emacs thinks you haven't sent it a complete key sequences is most likely because you've bound `C-c C-c` to a prefix command. Check the source of your major mode for any code that binds `C-c C-c` to something, there's probably something fishy there.

If you install `which-key`, you can turn on `which-key-mode`, then when you enter `C-c C-c` and wait a second, it will show you the name of the prefix map that you've accidentally assigned to `C-c C-c` at the bottom of the minibuffer.

## UPDATE

Knowing that the problem comes from emmet-mode, I found the following line in the source for that:

```
(define-key map (kbd "C-c C-c w") 'emmet-wrap-with-markup)
```

This is implicitly defining `C-c C-c` as an unamed prefix map in `emmet-mode-keymap`. Which means whenever that keymap is active, it's going to block whatever you've *previously* bound to `C-c C-c`.

To fix this, you could ask the emmet-mode maintainer to use `C-c C-w` instead. But they may have their reasons to do what they've done. You can over-ride it by redefining `C-c C-c` in emmet-mode-map *after* you load emmet-mode. Something like this:

```
(eval-after-load "emmet-mode"
   '(define-key emmet-mode-keymap (kbd "C-c C-c") 'oef-edit-in-browser))
```

You may want to add a new binding for `emmet-wrap-with-markup`. And this change will apply to `emmet-mode` whenever you use it, not just when you're using it with `oef-mode`. If that's not what you want you'll need to further tweak how and when you rebind the key.

Comment: The culprit is in emmet-mode.el  `(define-key map (kbd "C-c C-c w") 'emmet-wrap-with-markup)`

Comment: I put your code in my init file but it's not working. emmet-mode-map doesn't exist. I found another way to solve my problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In Aquamacs I have emmet-mode version 20161113 here `emmet-wrap-with-markup` is bound to `C-c w`. In emacs I have emmet-mode version 20180613 bound to `C-c C-c w`.

Comment: Sorry, the code should have referred to `emmet-mode-keymap`, not `emmet-mode-map`. I have corrected it.